# Postgres Combine Summed Values from 2 Queries / Tables into Single Row

Tags: postgresql

Say I had the following 2 queries, summing values from separate tables.

I would like the sum of recorded time

```
SELECT 
    SUM(minutes) as recorded_minutes,
    SUM(hours) as recorded_hours
FROM recorded_time
WHERE
    project_id = 1
```

To be combined with the sum of budgeted time in a single row

```
SELECT 
    SUM(minutes) as budgeted_minutes,
    SUM(hours) as budgeted_hours
FROM budgeted_time
WHERE
    project_id = 1
```

Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your queries,a bit you can use INNER JOIN(but that is for only one project_id unnecessary).

But in the second query you can so compare more than one project

> ```
> CREATE TABLE recorded_time(project_id int,hours int, minutes int);
> CREATE TABLE  budgeted_time(project_id int,hours int, minutes int);
> INSERT INTO recorded_time SELECT 1,13, 13;
> INSERT INTO recorded_time SELECT 1,13, 13;
> insert into recorded_time SELECT 2,14, 14;
> INSERT INTO recorded_time SELECT 2,13, 13;
> INSERT INTO budgeted_time SELECT 1,26, 26;
> INSERT INTO budgeted_time SELECT 1,26, 26;
> INSERT INTO budgeted_time SELECT 2,32, 32;
> INSERT INTO budgeted_time SELECT 2,33, 33;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT recorded_minutes,recorded_hours,budgeted_minutes,budgeted_hours FROM
> (SELECT 
>     MIN(project_id) project_id,
>     SUM(minutes) as recorded_minutes,
>     SUM(hours) as recorded_hours
> FROM recorded_time
> WHERE
>     project_id = 1) recorded
> INNER JOIN
> (SELECT 
>     MIN(project_id) AS project_id,
>     SUM(minutes) as budgeted_minutes,
>     SUM(hours) as budgeted_hours
> FROM budgeted_time
> WHERE
>     project_id = 1) budget ON budget.project_id = recorded.project_id
> ```

> ```
> recorded_minutes | recorded_hours | budgeted_minutes | budgeted_hours
> ---------------: | -------------: | ---------------: | -------------:
>               26 |             26 |               52 |             52
> ```

> ```
> SELECT recorded.*,budgeted_minutes,budgeted_hours FROM
> (SELECT 
>     project_id,
>     SUM(minutes) as recorded_minutes,
>     SUM(hours) as recorded_hours
> FROM recorded_time
> GROUP BY 
>     project_id) recorded
> INNER JOIN
> (SELECT 
>     project_id,
>     SUM(minutes) as budgeted_minutes,
>     SUM(hours) as budgeted_hours
> FROM budgeted_time
> GROUP BY
>     project_id) budget ON budget.project_id = recorded.project_id
> ORDER BY project_id
> ```
>
> ```
> project_id | recorded_minutes | recorded_hours | budgeted_minutes | budgeted_hours
> ---------: | ---------------: | -------------: | ---------------: | -------------:
>          1 |               26 |             26 |               52 |             52
>          2 |               27 |             27 |               65 |             65
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=146cfe4f9b786d943d5929cb41873f83)*

Comment: That's a bit more versatile, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I can use `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT recorded_minutes, recorded_hours, budgeted_minutes, budgeted_hours
FROM
    (SELECT 
        SUM(minutes) as recorded_minutes,
        SUM(hours) as recorded_hours
    FROM recorded_time
    WHERE
        project_id = 1) rt
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 
        SUM(minutes) as budgeted_minutes,
        SUM(hours) as budgeted_hours
    FROM budgeted_time
    WHERE
        project_id = 1) bt
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e2388/4/0

Comment: In this case any join would work (full, left , right, inner,cross )